# Yii2 unable to run console commands

Tags: php, terminal, yii2, console

When I'm trying to run yii2 console command - I just get list of commands in response:
The following commands are available:

```
- asset                        Allows you to combine and compress your JavaScript and CSS files.
    asset/compress (default)   Combines and compresses the asset files according to the given configuration.
    asset/template             Creates template of configuration file for [[actionCompress]].
...
```

No, I'm not just running `php yii`, I can run `php yii migrate/create test` and it will respond with list of command and do nothing.
Here is my yii file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Yii console bootstrap file.
 */

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php';

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/test.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/test-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/test.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/test-local.php'
);

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

And here is my console config:

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\FixtureController::class,
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => \yii\log\FileTarget::class,
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To use the migration commands, you must add the `yii\console\controllers\MigrateController` to the console configuration file .

I leave an example of how to add in the code below.

```php
    'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
            'migrationPath' => [
                '@console/migrations',
            ],
        ],
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\FixtureController::class,
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
        ],
    ],
```